# byte aligned to odd address. Does it violate access boundary theory?

Tags: byte, alignment

```
struct X {
char a;
char b;
int c;
};
```

In the above struct, member `b` is stored in an odd address. I checked this on a linux/x86 enviroment

Many web pages talks about inability of processors to access odd addresses. If it was true, then there should been padding of 1 byte between member `a` and `b`, such that `b` is stored in an even address.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Acessing a char at an odd address is always okay.  However, an int at an odd address could cause a problem.  However, the compiler will automatically add padding to between struct fields if needed.  I'm assuming C/C++ as your language.

Comment: But many doc says memory access is done according to the word size of the processor. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment. It says "when the computer's word size is 4 bytes (a byte meaning 8 bits), the data to be read should be at a memory offset which is some multiple of 4.".   So whats the catch here ?